# How should I do a rating for my ratings table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have added a five star rating and I am storing every rated value in the database

How should I do the rating for the product so I can use my rating starts to actually go to those many starts if I get a valid number

Here is the screen of my database table

[image]

so in the case the productid is 104, i want to get the rating of the that product as an verage i am trying to follow some logic in tutorials but how to amed that in mysql i am getting a little lost here

[https://calculator.academy/average-rating-calculator-star-rating/#f1p1|f2p0](https://calculator.academy/average-rating-calculator-star-rating/#f1p1%7Cf2p0)

Please guide if you can

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a separate row for each rating and not the number of times each rating was used like in the tutorial you linked to, a straight forward average would do the trick. In MySQL, this can be done with the [`avg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg) function:

```sql
SELECT AVG(rating)
FROM   ratings
WHERE  productid = 104
```